# IPhone app build and deliver to store without device

Tags: iphone, build, store

I have a simple question.

I use an old IPhone with ios version 3.1.3 and  I have to deliver an app for the ios version 5.0.

Is it possible to build and deliver an 5.0 app to the store without the correct 5.0 device?

Problem is, it isn't really cheap to buy every single ios version device.

I know it is probably necessary to test on a real device, but I only want to know is it theoretically possible do develop and deliver without the device.

thanks for your help

Matthias

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  Xcode comes with an iOS simulator that simulates iPhones and iPads running iOS 4.3 and 5.0.  However these don't fully match real devices, so you really should be testing on real devices.  There's an additional problem that a lot of functionality won't work on the simulator, such as in-app purchases and Game Center.  But for basic applications, you can scrape by.

If you're looking to reduce costs, iPod touches are almost identical to iPhones and a lot cheaper, so that's the low cost way of testing on a real device.  I would also upgrade your current device to iOS 4 if possible - iOS 3 is practically dead now, so it's better to test on a real device with iOS 4 than it is to try to support iOS 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to deliver an app without the correct version.

I found out, that it is even possible to deliver apps without an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

even though you can deploy apps without having an iOS device ..or having a device with lower iOS version..

but in future and generally a good advice i will give is to find someone with correct iOS device version(any other version will work too) and get him to try your app using ad-hoc distribution..that way you can get feedback of how your app will perform..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can anyway test most functionality by using the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

With the new Xcode, you don't need the device when you are building for release.
What you need to do is select iOS Device in the menu, then Product -> Archive.
Then you will see the "Validate" and "Submit" options in your organizer.